# Spring StandardServletMultipartResolver

Tags: spring, servlets, multipart, resolver

I was wondering where is located the code that automatically create a temporary file when you send a multipart request using StandardServletMultipartResolver?

Can i disable that behavior? I want to decide how its going to be stored and where. I don't want spring to do it for me.

I'm considering creating my own resolver but I cant find information on how to disable spring default behavior.

Comment: That depends on your servlet container... The `StandardServletMultipartResolver` delegates the file handling to the servlet container using the multipart file support as available in a servlet 3.0 container. So how that implementation works depends on your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from API [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.html) `StandardServletMultipartResolver` does not support temporary file configuration on resolver level rather it is to be done on servlet registration level -

> In order to use Servlet 3.0 based multipart parsing, you need to mark the affected servlet with a "multipart-config" section in `web.xml`, or with a `MultipartConfigElement` in programmatic servlet registration, or (in case of a custom servlet class) possibly with a `MultipartConfig` annotation on your servlet class. 
>   
> Configuration settings such as maximum sizes or ***storage locations*** need to be applied at that ***servlet registration level***; Servlet 3.0 does ***not*** allow for them to be set at the `MultipartResolver` level.

So either you can configure it on servlet or switch to `CommonsMultipartResolver` which has the support to set the temp directory out-of-the-box as it inherits it from `CommonsFileUploadSupport.setUploadTempDir` (*see respective docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsFileUploadSupport.html#setUploadTempDir-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-)*)